# Calculating total percent in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I am new to tableau and need to display the total percent for each test officer of all 19 categories combined. for example, test officer 15716 would have a total percent compliant as 47.5 in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: can you add a little context on how you get to your number of 47.5%?  On the pill for the table calculation there is options for the level to compute the calculation at for cases such as this which will help, but with out knowing which numbers leader to 47.5 in your dataset it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Each Test Officer is required to meet the target amount in system target column. The sum of count is how many they have done in each category. So for test officer 15716, he did 5 of the 8 required in category 1 and so on.  The 47.5% is the overall percentage complete (total required in target column / total complete)

Answer (score 3):

Use a LOD ([Level Of Detail](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm)) expression

```
{ FIXED [Test_Officer_SAPID] : SUM([Actual_Total]) / SUM([System_Target]) }
```

**47.5%** is the [average of averages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect/95912). I assume you are actually looking for **57.5%** (23 divided by 40). Not (63%+33%+66%+n%)/(3+n)

Comment: Good solution. Still depending on what dimensions you have in play in your viz, you may not need an LOD calc, but can simplify to an aggregate calculation (the part between the colon and the closing curly brace in LOD calc). That can be more efficient and flexible than an LOD. Sometimes the aggregate calc can work at multiple levels of detail, while the LOD calc is fixed to a specific level of detail by design.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is sub-totals and grand totals. Using discrete values in your table prevents the totals from working. Instead of discrete measures you can use continuous (green) by switching to a [measure names/measure values solution](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-display-measures-in-a-table/) instead. That will activate the subtotals (which you need) and also grand totals.